# Equivalent of MySQL's `kill query` in Apache SparkSQL?

Tags: apache-spark-sql

Is there an equivalent of `MySQL`'s command `kill query` (as defined [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/kill.html)) in Apache SparkSQL?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am providing the answer myself here (got some tip from my colleagues).

There may be no direct equivalent commands in SparkSQL, but one can use the WebUI for Spark to achieve similar effects.  Note that under the job listing there is a link called `kill`

c.f. [Monitoring and Instrumentation (Official Doc of Apache Spark)](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html)